# HAProxy stick table rate expiration

Tags: haproxy

I am using HAProxy on Ubuntu to perform some rate limiting. Here are the most important fragments from my config:

```
global
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners


frontend http-listener
    bind *:80 accept-proxy

    http-request track-sc1 src table st_ip_req_rate

    http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc_http_req_rate(1) gt 100 }
    http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc_http_err_rate(1) gt 200 }

    default_backend no-match-backend


backend st_ip_req_rate
    stick-table  type ip  size 100k  expire 24h store http_req_rate(10s),http_err_rate(24h)


backend no-match-backend
    http-request deny deny_status 503
```

I did not include my actual backends here but within this example my expectations would be:

1. requests are usually answered with a status 503
2. the 101st request within a sliding window of 10 seconds is answered with a status 429
3. the first request after 200 requests within a sliding window of 24 hours that have been [answered with a 4xx status code](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#sc0_http_err_rate) is answered with a status 429

I expect the sliding window to work for the `sc_http_req_rate` because the example [this blog post](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/four-examples-of-haproxy-rate-limiting/) also uses a rate over 10s with an `expire 30s`. However the requests are denied with a 429 after 100 requests. When I look into the stick table like such:

```
$ echo "show table st_ip_req_rate" | sudo socat unix:/run/haproxy/admin.sock -
# table: st_ip_req_rate, type: ip, size:102400, used:10
0x7f133c01b8d8: key=192.1.2.3 use=0 exp=86389546 http_req_rate(10000)=639 http_err_rate(86400000)=0
...
```

I can see that the http_req_rate does not decline.

Am I wrong to expect different behavior or is this a bug? I checked the link below and no known bug seemed to match at the time (25.03.2021).

```
$ haproxy -v
HA-Proxy version 2.2.11-1ppa1~focal 2021/03/18 - https://haproxy.org/
Status: long-term supported branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q2 2025.
Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.2.11.html
Running on: Linux 5.4.0-67-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 18:03:38 UTC 2021 x86_64
```

The answer from [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/947063/617089) suggests to use `table_http_req_rate` for a similar problem. This would not apply here, as my request rates also don't decline if there are no requests for > 10s.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this as well. It seems to be [regression](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/1196). Switching to 2.3.X (specifically 2.3.7) resolved the issue for me. If you're running it from docker using `lts-apline` as I was, you'll have to switch to a different image for now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know where I can find out when they plan to release this fix on the 2.2 LTS version?

Comment: No idea unfortunately. 2.3.X does not seem to be LTS, so my guess is they'll backport the fix and release as 2.2.12 or something. The question is probably more suited to the [haproxy issue tracker](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues) or the [haproxy docker image issue tracker](https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy/issues), maybe even the [official docker images repo where the changes are made](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/labels/library%2Fhaproxy).

Comment: HAProxy 2.2.12 has been released and solves the problem for me. If you update your answer to reflect that, I will accept it.